# Computers successfully connect through VPN to shared folders, but do not appear listed in the network explorer

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn

I have 2 computers, both running windows 10.

Computer A is hosting a VPN using *incoming connection* and computer B connects to it from an outside network.

Both computers can connect to each other's shared folders by typing either the ip address or the computer name directly in the explorer path. However, neither sees the other in the network explorer window.

How can I make it so the computers are listed in the network window, similarly to what happens when on a local network without vpn?

Comment: See if the following article can help with you: http://woshub.com/network-computers-not-showing-windows-10/#:~:text=In%20some%20cases%2C%20Windows%20computer,Change%20Settings%20%2D%3E%20Network%20ID.

Comment: @Candy The groups are already set up properly. When both computers are on the same lan they can see each other fine, it's just that when one of them connects through vpn that they no longer appear listed in the network explorer